# How to change this SQL query to PL/SQL command line or code? SELECT username, account_status FROM dba_users;

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to change this SQL query to PL/SQL command line or code?

```
SELECT username, account_status FROM dba_users;
```

I tried

```
DECLARE
  user_name VARCHAR2(20) := 'username';
  account_status VARCHAR2(20) := 'account_status';
BEGIN
  FOR user_name IN (SELECT username FROM dba_users) LOOP
    FOR account_status IN (SELECT account_status FROM dba_users) LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(user_name.username || ' - ' || user_record.account_status);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

it works but the output is repeating

Comment: Why are you doing this? You already have a simple query that apparently works how you want.

Comment: If this is just an exercise in how to nest loops, it repeats because the inner query has no filtering condition and just lists all users' account statuses every time. You could add a `where` clause to the inner cursor, although you would be fetching the same row you already have from the outer loop, so as it stands the inner loop is unnecessary anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is pure SQL:

```
SQL> select username, account_status from dba_users where rownum <= 5;

USERNAME             ACCOUNT_STATUS
-------------------- --------------------
SYS                  OPEN
AUDSYS               LOCKED
SYSTEM               OPEN
SYSBACKUP            LOCKED
SYSDG                LOCKED
```

To "convert" it into PL/SQL, use **one** loop (why using two?):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select username, account_status from dba_users where rownum <= 5)
  3    loop
  4      dbms_output.put_line(cur_R.username ||' - '|| cur_r.account_status);
  5    end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /
SYS - OPEN
AUDSYS - LOCKED
SYSTEM - OPEN
SYSBACKUP - LOCKED
SYSDG - LOCKED

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Your code, fixed: if you use nested loops (once again, no need for that), you have to **correlate** one loop query to another - that's what you are missing - see **line #4**:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_user in (select username from dba_users where rownum <= 5) loop
  3      for cur_acc in (select account_status from dba_users
  4                      where username = cur_user.username
  5                     )
  6      loop
  7        dbms_output.put_line(cur_user.username ||' - '|| cur_acc.account_status);
  8      end loop;
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /
SYS - OPEN
AUDSYS - LOCKED
SYSTEM - OPEN
SYSBACKUP - LOCKED
SYSDG - LOCKED

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this block:

```
cl scr
set SERVEROUTPUT ON

BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT distinct username FROM dba_users order by username) LOOP
    FOR j IN (SELECT  distinct account_status FROM dba_users where username=i.username order by account_status) LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(i.username || ' - ' || j.account_status);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```